# Moving changes from one instance to another

Tags: managed-package, package-install

I need to move changes from dev1 instance to dev2 and create upgraded managed package in dev2. I create unmanaged package in dev1 (managed are not allowed there) and try to install to dev2, it shows error about duplicates that come from a previously installed unmanaged package in dev2. So I try to uninstall previous package, and it can't uninstall because there is a component that is referenced by the managed package, the same package that I need to upgrade. It doesn't specify which component.
How can I pass changes from dev1 to dev2 in a reasonable way without deleting existing managed package in dev2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using the ANT Migration Toolkit to move your changes. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/

Comment: Eventually, I went with manually moving the changes, I thought there was not too much of changes to spend time learning this tool. I skimmed through the video showing it in action, maybe I will use it when there are more changes. Thanks.